# Why $(window).width() and $(window).height() don't change in iPad Cordova Apps?

Tags: jquery, ipad, cordova

Why $(window).width() and $(window).height() don't change in iPad Cordova Apps ?

"Basically, remove "width=device-width, height=device-height" from the meta tag for viewport. It's an Apple bug"

This is a Question and Answer post, because i have been trying to figure this out for a while and couldn't... until i found this post:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/PhoneGap/RN8S4iMbzQU

wich says it is an apple bug reported at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323

..

Answer (score 0):

"Basically, remove "width=device-width, height=device-height" from the meta tag for viewport. It's an Apple bug" :)